Hello I have a problem with my .ldf configuration for user automation in Windows Server (ADDS)
I'm a Student in IT and i've been blocked since a few hours by this problem :
I don't understand what is the problem here is the configuration of my .ldf :
dn: CN=Henri CANTONEY,OU=Users,DC=hoywo,DC=lan
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
givenName: Henri
sn: CANTONEY
initials: HC
displayName: Henri HC CANTONEY
sAMAccountName: HC101
userPrincipalName: HC101@hoywo.lan
userAccountControl: 512
description: Domain User Enterprise
department: Restauration
title: Head Chef
-
dn: CN=Anne HALFABETH,OU=Users,DC=hoywo,DC=lan
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
givenName: Anne
sn: HALFABETH
initials: AH
displayName: Anne AH HALFABETH
sAMAccountName: AH101
userPrincipalName: AH101@hoywo.lan
userAccountControl: 512
description: Domain User Enterprise
department: Maintenance
title: Cleaning Technician
-
dn: CN=Alex TERRIEUR,OU=Users,DC=hoywo,DC=lan
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
givenName: Alex
sn: TERRIEUR
initials: AT
displayName: Alex AT TERRIEUR
sAMAccountName: AT101
userPrincipalName: AT101@hoywo.lan
userAccountControl: 512
description: Domain User Enterprise
department: Groundskeeping
title: Grounds Technician
-
dn: CN=Alex XAMIN,OU=Users,DC=hoywo,DC=lan
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
givenName: Alex
sn: XAMIN
initials: AX
displayName: Alex AX CEPTION
sAMAccountName: AC101
userPrincipalName: AC101@hoywo.lan
userAccountControl: 512
description: Domain User Enterprise
department: Medical
title: Doctor
-
dn: CN=Sarah CROCHE,OU=Users,DC=hoywo,DC=lan
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
givenName: Sarah
sn: CROCHE
initials: SC
displayName: Sarah SC CROCHE
sAMAccountName: SC01T
userPrincipalName: SC01T@hoywo.lan
userAccountControl: 512
description: Domain User Enterprise
department: IT
title: Technical Assistant
-

I've tryed to integrate this in the CMD using Administrator via the ldifde -i -f c:... (thefile)
and i've an error happenning in line 16 i was thinking it was about the - between my users block.
I've Firstly tryed to use a CSV but i get a problem when i cannot join the domain for i don't know what F reason. Can y'all Script Automation enjoyers help me please ? :D
